# Kali Dns Problems

Tags: networking, dns, kali-linux

I have a problem. So, when I connect to any wi-fi station I can't use google or yandex. I solved that. The thing was in dns. I added google dns servers to 'resolv.conf' and it worked fine. However, after reconnection it does the same thing and I have to write manually or with script to set dns.
Is there any way to make this process automatically when the computer connects to the network? I tried to do it through the network/interfaces post-up and if-up.d . But it didn't help. The code is like that.

interfaces:

```
auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    post-up /etc/network/ssh_and_dns_start
```

ssh_and_dns_start:

```
#!/bin/sh

add_dns()
{
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
}

add_dns
exit 0
```

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thank you very much! But is there any chance to set default dns settings? Or should I add these dns to every network manually?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? In the link there are several options to set your dns server. And what do you mean by "dns to every network manually"?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen there is a method for setting dns for one network through Network Settings. But I want these setting for every network that I will connect in the future. Kinda default settings. That is my question.

Comment: Those settings should work on all networks you connect to.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

```
interface "wlan0"{
  supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was hackish and probably not the way you would want to do it, but if you just need the bleeping thing working...

So I had set up Kali connected to ethernet and when I went to add a wifi connection, no DNS. */etc/resolv.conf* pointed to something like */run/resolvconf/...* which pointed to yet another thing.

There's not the option to `sudo` yourself and `vim /etc/resolv.conf` - for a few reasons.  So logout, login as root, delete the symlink */etc/resolvconf/...* points to, then `vim /etc/resolv.conf` and add the nameservers you want, e.g.

```
nameserver your.gateway.ip
```

or

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Before this, you can try

```
root@kali# dhclient wlan0
```

to get some information.  I didn't find it very helpful.  Editing the wireless connection settings with the GUI didn't work for me, even though it picked up on the nameservers.  I just went ahead and deleted the symlink for */etc/resolv.conf* and created */etc/resolv.conf*, and all was fine.